# Is there a technical reason why Express routes are defined with a leading forward slash?

Tags: node.js, http, express, url-routing

I'm quite new to Node.js and Express (and relatively new to http stuff in general).  While going through various tutorials, I got curious about why the paths defined in the routes always have a leading forward slash.  You would have something like `router.get('/sub_path', handler);` which would be mounted using something like `app.use('/parent', the_router);` and the whole thing would then be accessed by going somewhere like `http://localhost:3000/parent/sub_path`.  I tried omitting the slashes in the calls to `get()` and `use()` and sure enough things stopped working correctly.

Is there a technical reason that the slashes are necessary or was it just an arbitrary design decision (perhaps for consistency or clarity or something)?  I didn't see any errors in the server, so is there maybe a case where the lack of slashes actually does something useful?

Comment: I doubt there would have been a "technical" reason, because its trivial to make express join path fragments correctly (see `path.join()` from nodejs API ). The reason might be more or less enforcing a semantic pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Well, when you have an URL like `http://www.somedomain.com/somepath`, the path in that URL is `/somepath`.  It's not `somepath`.  It's `/somepath`.  So, if you want to match that above URL with a route, you need to match `/somepath`.

I supposed that it would have been possible for Express to "assume" every single route string had an implicit `"/"` on the front of it and not make you type it, but it would be a bit misleading.  The route you're asking to match starts with a `/`.

You are allowed to use a regex to match a route, but that's the only case I've seen where you don't use a leading `/`.

For further discussion of actual developer motivation at the time of designing/writing the code, you'd have to ask people who actually wrote Express.  Not something we can speak to here.