# Cannot POST and Cannot GET (Node.JS and MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I am following an introductory course on Node and Mongo, where I test the server using postman to get and post. I keep getting error 404 not found for both GET and POST requests. I verified that the mongoDB is connected. Any input on where I might have overlooked anything is greatly appreciated.

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 

const app = express(); 

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
    .connect("mongodb+srv://John:john123@cluster0.nmtde.mongodb.net/mern-shopping?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('mongoDB connected.'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));


const items = require('./routes/api/items.js'); 
app.use('api/items',items);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// listen on the port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

items.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Item = require('../../models/Item');

// @route GET api/items
// @desc GET ALL Items
// @access Public
router.get("/", (req,res) => {
    Item.find()
        .sort({ date: -1 }) // -1 for descending
        .then(items => res.json(items))
})

// @route GET api/items
// @desc Create a post
// @access Public
router.post("/", (req,res) => {
    const newItem = new Item({
        name: req.body.name
        // date is inserted automatically
    });

    newItem.save().then(item => res.json(item));
})

module.exports = router;
```

Item.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create schema
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
module.exports = Item;
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting in Postman? FYI, I believe you should use `app.use("/api/items", items)` (not the `/` prefix). See https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#path-examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a technical reason why Express routes are defined with a leading forward slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38650755/283366)

Comment: Yes, you should **start URL with a `/`** and **don't add a `/` in the end**, because in the sub-routers should also be started with a `/` and if both parent and sub router will have a `/` in beginning and ending respectively, then route will become /parent//sub